# How to have different colours for all treatments in 2x2x2 design in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, lm, confidence-interval

I have a 2 x 2 x 2 design, where data(dat) looks like this.

```
  bucket  size  level   marbles distance 
  Blue    Large Low     80        30     
  Blue    Large High    9         33     
  Blue    Small Low     91        1      
  Blue    Small High    2         11     
  White   Large Low     80        21
  White   Large High    9         13
  White   Small Low     91        52
  White   Small High    2         17
```

I want to plot the relationship between   and use the following code:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x = marbles, y = distance, colour=size, shape=level)) +
geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", fill=NA) + facet_grid(~bucket)
```

In addition to having different colours for size, I want to have different colours and shape for the levels. However, I'm not sure how this can be achieved using this code. Also, is there a way to add 95% confidence intervals to these for the corresponding treatments